# globular vs regex in find

Tags: regex, bash, find

I am trying to find file names similar to this: `fsimage_0000000000501205926`

This is what I tried :

works:  `find . -name 'fsimage_???????????????????' -mtime -1`

Following another SO post I tried this and it doesn't work:

`find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^fsimage_[0-9]{19}' -mtime -1`

*** EDIT:
As suggested escaping the curly braces doesn't work either.

What I am doing wrong with the regex command ? I am using 4.4.2 GNU findutils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/fsimage_[0-9]{19}'
```

PS: If you're on OSX then use:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/fsimage_[0-9]{19}'
```

Comment: That is because matched filename is `./fsimage_0000000000501205926` causing `^fsimage_[0-9]{19}` regex to fail. `-regex '\./fsimage_[0-9]{19}'` should work for files in current directory only.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the same impression after writing the comment. Excellent observation. Thanks again.